# Missing MSVCP70.dll

Tags: windows

I'm trying to run a program that says it wants `MSVCP70.dll`.  Where can I obtain this?  I assume it's some Microsoft Visual C redistributable, but it seems like MS DLL numbering has nothing to do with what the package name is (20xx, or .NET 1.x...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of visual c++ 2002 , which dosen't have a proper redistributable - by right the software that uses is it supposed to come with it.

Unfortunately most of the sites that seem to have it seem dodgy, so i can't recommend any specific download place

Comment: According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922 , the developer of the software should have included a copy with your application. You can probably find the file on some dll download website (yes, they are all dodgy) and scan for virus. Just put it in the application installation directory and it should work.

Comment: You usually end up running into the missing DLL on 64bit versions of windows.  Usually 32bit will run the application fine.

Comment: Here's [a copy](http://ompldr.org/vYThsZQ/msvcp70-v7.0.9466.0-x86.zip). Many DLL download websites actually have unmodified files, the problem is the truckload of "get our DLL fixer tool" advertisements you need to get through before the actual file.